# Does msync sync all files on the filesystem to the disk like fsync on ext3?

Tags: linux, ext3, fsync

as far as I know, on most ext3 system with log mode "data=ordered",  fsync will not only sync the file specified with the fd, but will sync all files on the filesystem, and this problem has not been fixed before kernel 2.6.30

And I got a question, that is, is msync do the same thing as fsync does?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a citation of a source which describes this behaviour? It's not my understanding.

Comment: to MarkR you can google "linux ext3 firefox 3" and you can find lots of articles taking about this

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, it's a feature. Ext3 is a journaled file system. data=ordered means you are asking for the changes to the file system to be written *in the order they are made*.

So, when you are asking to sync the changes to a particular file you have to commit all the previous changes, whether to that files or others, or you are breaking the directive to keep the data in order. For this reason I suspect that msync will behave in the same way, although I haven't checked.

In fact, one can argue that if it doesn't it's a file system bug...

Comment: hi gby, thanks for your explanation
I think I just misunderstanding the behaviour of ext3

Answer (score 0):

Reading the various articles, I don't think that's true at all. It does not flush all dirty data to disc if you do one fsync. It only flushes the metadata belonging to the same file.

Moreover, the problem described with data=ordered, seems to be that it waits for other pending IO requests to the same device, even though it should logically be higher priority. Not for all dirty data to be flushed (like sync()).

I would like to do an experiment to find out.

Comment: hi MarkR  
I read another article, and it seems that with data=ordered on ext3, fsync will sync the dirty page of the specified file and all the journal logs on that filesystem  

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=  
http://kerneltrap.org/node/14148  
The whole point of fsync() is that it should sync only that one file, and 
avoid syncing all the other stuff that is going on, and ext3 violates 
that, because it ends up having to sync the whole log, or something like 
that.  
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=

Comment: I'm still pretty sure that it does not sync all dirty blocks on the fs. Maybe it syncs all the metadata - which could be bad if you have atime enabled and have read lots of files recently.